# Can a Tunisian child with an EU residence card, travelling with an EU citizen, visit the UK without needing a UK visa?

Tags: uk, international-travel, italian-residents, tunisian-citizens

I'm an Italian citizen living in Italy.
I want to travel to London for holiday week, with my child but he have card resident EU family Italy, not European (Tunisian Citizen).
My question is can my child travel without visa?

My child has an article 10 residence card. He will be traveling with an EU citizen (me).

Comment: For clarity, does he have an Article 10 or Article 20 residence card https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card? You can check if he needs a visa using this tool https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y

Comment: Card resident eu of my chidreen of article 10 in italy , he can travel accompany citizen European ? But without to obtain card permit family in uk ? , just for travel same week. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Walid, the answer by phoog here seems to answer your question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/148970/my-husband-is-italian-and-im-an-african-living-in-italy-with-permanent-stay-ca?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a visa to travel to the UK with a *Carta di Soggiorno di Familiare di Un Cittadino Dell'Unione* as long as you travel with or travel to join the EU family member.

(Note that this applies before Brexit; after Brexit the rules may change and a visa may be required.)